# Include of non-modular header inside framework module with cocoa touch framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I have mixed cocoa touch framework (A) with swift and objective-c files, and embedded 3rd party framework (does not have pod). Then I add this framework A to my app and get error about non-modular header inside..., but this error is for 3rd party framework's header. I have set allow non modular includes to YES.

Any ideas, how can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the header file target membership from Project/Private to Public in the File Inspector. If that doesn't work make sure you're only importing the framework as a header file and not an implementation file. Also check that the import is being done in an implementation file.

Comment: Do you mean 3rd party framework's header file? If so, there is no such option in file inspector.
Also cannot import in implementation file, because in header file, there is reference to typedef int from framework's header file